# How do you remove hearthfire wings?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

What are the exact commands I need to use to remove the kitchen from my house in Falkreath? I can't figure it out.

Comment: I don't believe it's possible, once the wing is built.

Comment: If the workbench in the room or outside doesn't let you do it directly, there's no way to do it; at least without mods.

Comment: Uninstall Hearthfire and then reinstall the DLC. Console commands make the DLC and the house very broken.